# Does a form of energy exist without any medium?

Tags: energy, sun, space

Does the Sun contain fire? Or some pure form of energy?

If space has no air how can fire exist there?  It may exist cause a burning piece of magnesium keeps on burning in vacuum but, to start fire, oxygen is required.

Comment: The sun is not made of fire (a result of oxygenation), it is made of hydrogen [plasma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_(physics)).

Comment: kyle sir,it is also a form of energy ,isnt it?so,can a. form of energy exist in vacuum?This was my actual question

Comment: Hydrogen is not energy, it is an [atom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom). The sun *produces* energy through [hydrogen fusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_fusion), which releases [photons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photons) (energy).

Comment: And since space is not a vacuum, I don't see what the issue is.

Comment: Thank you sir,if space is not vacuum,which gas is found?

Comment: Primarily neutral hydrogen atoms, but you can also find most elements up to iron and compounds like dust (e.g., carbon molecules, not dust that you find in your house)

Comment: I do not think that a burning piece of magnesium keeps on burning in vaccum - as there is no oygen, and burning would mean a reaction of magnesium and oxygen. But that's assumung a perfect vacuum; I could imagine magnesium can still burn in a partly vaccuum where paper would stop to burn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you call a medium; I assume you refer to matter as a medium.

Then, roughly speaking: yes, there is radiation, like light, or heat radiation, that can exist without matter as medium. I think you could call this "energy" in this sense.
You can transfer light through a vacuum, of course.

The sun, fire or burning magnesium are about matter that is hot - which is very different.

Answer (score 0):

Like a rocket provides oxygen to burn fuel in space, so the sun provides its own energy.  Like you, I'm not necessarily convinced the space in an of itself it not a medium since light travels at a constant speed within it and matter is capable of traveling within it.  Planets bleed their own atmospheres into space as well.

Please see the about page:
https://physics.stackexchange.com/about